# Python EOFError for value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, eoferror

Long time lurker, first time poster. Test cases are returning a Traceback EOFError for the `country_name = input()` line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File “/usercode/file0.py”, line 16 in <module> 
    country_name = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Nothing fancy, the code gets the value of a key in a dictionary (“data”) based on user input (“country_name”). I’ve tried running in multiple IDEs and it works fine for me, reindenting, tried `str(input())` etc.

```
data = {
    'Singapore': 1,
    'Ireland': 6,
    'United Kingdom': 7,
    'Germany': 27,
    'Armenia': 34,
    'United States': 17,
    'Canada': 9,
    'Italy': 74
}
 
for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value)
 
while True:
    country_name = input()
 
    if country_name in data.keys():
        print("The economic rank is: ", data[country_name])
    else:
        print('Not found')
```

UPDATED, improvements per comments/answers:

```
data = {
    'Singapore': 1,
    'Ireland': 6,
    'United Kingdom': 7,
    'Germany': 27,
    'Armenia': 34,
    'United States': 17,
    'Canada': 9,
    'Italy': 74
}

for key, value in data.items():
    print(key,value)

try:
    while True:
        country_name = input("Enter a country: ")

        if country_name in data.keys():
            print(f"The economic rank of {country_name} is {data[country_name]}.", flush=True)
            exit()
        else:
            print("Country not found.")

except EOFError:
    pass
```

UPDATE:
It turns out the test cases weren't passing, because the test cases were written so strictly that they were expecting a `get()` method. Once those were removed, the test cases passed once I added an exit per the modified code (above), per the comments below.

Comment: Your code works for me. It can be simplified but it works as expected. Can you post the full text of the assignment and also the full traceback.

Comment: Can you provide any test case that is giving error?

Comment: Testcases might be trying with an empty input. Also wrap that call inside a try catch in case you have other exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @buran. Just posted the Traceback received by the test cases.

Comment: @Navaneeth Sen. Thanks, pondered that too, I will. The input being provided for the test case is Germany, which should return 27. I don’t have access to the code for the test cases, it’s a third party GUI.

Comment: How do you run the test case? This would happen if the script was loaded in an environment where stdin either exhausted or closed. Your script prompts forever, but did your test harness push data into it forever? The only way to test it is to start pumping data an wait for a power outage.

Comment: If you input `Germany` and then close stdin, the second loop fails.

Comment: I guess another way to say it is that your test found a bug. Yay! Your code needs a way to terminate gracefully. Maybe a special command word or an empty line. If its not supposed to be used by humans, then catching the EOF would be a great way to terminate.

Comment: @tdelaney. It’s run in a 3rd party GUI. You’re right, the test cases provides input for Germany and the United States, then stops. Hmm, why those are failing, I don’t know.

Comment: Failing after the correct outputs for those two countries or before? This isn't a GUI itslef... does the GUI execute this program and read its stdout? Does it expect multiple questions and answers or just one? If it wants one reault before pushing in the next question, then you may need to add `flush=True` to the print.

Comment: @tdelaney. Gotcha, thanks. I’ll terminate my code gracefully. :)

Comment: @tdelaney. I’ll start with catching an EOF error to terminate then trying flush=True in print. Trying now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the test case hits EOF (*nix: Ctrl-D, Windows: Ctrl-Z+Return), this wil raise an EOFError. I can create the same error when I do **Cmd+D** in my Mac after running the program.

The test case might be exiting in a similar fashion.

Cant you just wrap it in a try-catch and ignore the EOFError as shown below:

```
try:
    while True:
        country_name = input()

        if country_name in data.keys():
            print("The economic rank is: ", data[country_name])
        else:
            print('Not found')
except:
    pass
```

Comment: A naked except isn't a good idea, it masks all of the program fails. `EOFError` would be good. But this is also a design issue. If this program is meant to be used by humans on the command line, forcing a ctrl-c or ctrl-d isn't user friendly.

Comment: I agree. I just left it naked for @Tucker to handle as per his expectation.

Comment: I think it would be better to only catch EOFError as that what OP is seeing.

Comment: Thanks @NavaneethSen. Updated the code in post. I'm too new to upvote your answer. A little help guys?